# How to make your text wrap inside a row?

Tags: flutter

I have a text widget inside of a row, who's text I'm retrieving from API, and can tend to get long sometimes. I want the text to wrap and move to next line when it gets too long, however its overflowing.
Is there a way to fix this ? 
Thanks

My code

```
  return  ListView.builder(
       itemCount: values == null ? 0 : values.length,
       itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
         return Ink(
           child: InkWell(
             child: Card(
                 child: Padding(
                   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                   child: Column(
                     children: <Widget>[
                     .......
                       Row(children: <Widget>[Icon(Icons.account_balance, size: 13.0, color: Colors.grey),
                         Padding(
                           padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                           child: Text(values[index].societyName, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 15.0), maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.clip,),   //TEXT HERE 
                         )],),
                    .....
                     ],
                   ),
                 ),
               ),

           ),
         );
       },
     );
```

**Edit:**

I tried using Expanded (and Flexible ) to wrap my row, however it gives the following error:

```
I/flutter (16255): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (16255): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter (16255): RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
I/flutter (16255): When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is
I/flutter (16255): in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a
I/flutter (16255): flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining
I/flutter (16255): space in the vertical direction.
I/flutter (16255): These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child
I/flutter (16255): cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.
I/flutter (16255): Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible
I/flutter (16255): children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size
I/flutter (16255): themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and
I/flutter (16255): then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum
I/flutter (16255): constraints provided by the parent.
```

It's owing to the fact that I have my column inside a ListView Card.
Is there any other alternative to fix this ?

I tried the suggestion given in the console, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have same question and solved!

check this, it has example code and screenshots
https://gist.github.com/yamarane/9269513a3c21eafb93a782fc387b9785

**UPDATE(Working!)**:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(body: Some()),
    );
  }
}

var values = [
  "111111111111111111111111111qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq",
  "222222222222222222222222222222222",
  "333333333333333333333333333",
  "4"
];

class Some extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: values == null ? 0 : values.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Ink(
          child: InkWell(
            child: Card(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.account_balance, size: 13.0, color: Colors.grey),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                      child: Text(
                        values[index],
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 15.0),
                      ), //TEXT HERE
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! I tried it, however still gives error, Ive written an Edit in my ques for it!

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `Row`, which wraps your `Text`, is wrapped inside a `Column`, and therefore it does not have a defined width. Wrap your `Row` with `Expanded` to give a predefined width to fill the remaining space.

```
Expanded(
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Icon(
        Icons.account_balance,
        size: 13.0,
        color: Colors.grey
      ),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
      child: Text(
        values[index].societyName,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 15.0), 
        maxLines: 2,
        overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
      ), //TEXT HERE 
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Hi! I tried it, however still gives error, Ive written an Edit in my ques for it!

Comment: Put your `Expanded` one level below your `Column`

Answer (score 0):

```
Flexible(
    child:  Padding(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
          child: Text(values[index].societyName, 
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 15.0), 
                maxLines: 2, 
                overflow: TextOverflow.clip,),   //TEXT HERE 
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi! I tried it, however still gives error, Ive written an Edit in my ques for it!

Answer (score 0):

try Expanded property

```
Expanded(
  child: Text(values[index].societyName, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 
 15.0), maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.clip,),
 )
```