# can't wrap my long text inside a card in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to put a text inside a card and make the card a bit flexible whenever there is a long text it goes to the next line automatically and the card gets langer

```
Widget ServiceCard (BuildContext context,double price){
  return Container(
    height: 100,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12,right: 8,left: 8),
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    child: Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)
      ),
      color: Colors.white,
      elevation: 8,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            top: 8,
            left: 8,
            child: Text("\$$price"),
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: 8,
            top: 8,
            child: Container(
//              height: 70,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                      child: Text("غسيل شعر",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),)
                  ),
                  Opacity(
                      opacity:0.7,
                      child: Text(
                          "يتم تصفيف الشعر وغسيل يتم تصفيف الشعر وغسيل يتم تصفيف الشعر وغسيل"

                      )
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

with this code im having the text goes over the card and not going to the next line and even the card is in a constent heghit not wrapped

Comment: Hey Check this answer and question, similar one. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56454824/11542801

Comment: You will need to use a Flexible for your text container

Answer (score 1):

To make `Text` wrap on overflow, ideally it has to be sized to full width and `maxLines` property must be set to `null`.

However, I can see that you have encountered an "edge-case" - all your text is placed in a `Stack` widget, which does not fit its children in width by default.

To solve this, change your `Positioned(...)` widget to `Positioned.fill`.

e.g.

```dart
Positioned.fill(
  right: 8,
  top: 8,
  child: Container(
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, // You might want to use this, too - this stretches all children in width by default
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          child: Text("غسيل شعر", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16))
        ),
        Opacity(
          opacity: 0.7,
          child: Text(
            "يتم تصفيف الشعر وغسيل يتم تصفيف الشعر وغسيل يتم تصفيف الشعر وغسيل",
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, // I assume this would be helpful too, if your language reads from right to left.
          )
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: thanks for the response .. it really helped in the text issue YOUR AWESOME!

Comment: but sadly that's not my only issue, the card is not fitting for the content size.. do you have any clue?

Comment: was this issue present before you made the changes according to my answer? In any case, I'd need more details to help further.